# Python - Split pdf or powerpoint by pixel location?

Tags: python, pdf, powerpoint, text-extraction

I will explain my dilemma first: I have several thousand powerpoint files (.ppt) that I need to extract the text. The problem is the text is is disorganized in the file and when read as a complete page it makes no sense for what I need (it would read in the example: line 1, line 3, line 2, line 4, line 5).

I was using `tika` to read the files initially. I then thought if I converted to pdf using `glob` and `win32com.client` that I would have some better luck but it's basically the same result. The picture here is an example of what the text is like.

So now my idea now is if I can section the pdf or ppt by pixel location (and save to separate temp files if needed, opened, and read that way) I can keep things in order and get what I need. Although the text moves around within each box, the black outline boxes are always roughly in the same location.

I cannot find anything to split an individual pdf page though, only multiple pages into a single page. Does anyone have an idea how to go about doing this?

I need to read the text in box one together (line 1 and line 2) and load into a dictionary or some other container, and the same for the second box. For reference there is only one slide in the powerpoint.

[image]

Comment: Are these old-format `.ppt` files (pre 2007) or `.pptx` files?

Comment: They're old, all `.ppt`

For reference I have been making progress with the method I suggested above. First `ppt` to `pdf` using `win32com`, second `pdf` to `jpg` using `pdf2image`, cropping to my needed frame locations with `PIL`, and last reading the image with `pytesseract`. No the prettiest nor is it perfect but maybe if I massage the images tomorrow a bit it will help. and FYI the screen shot in the description is a very simplified version of what I'm working with, part of why it's bee difficult just reading the text

Comment: Ahh, I see. I'll remove my answer then since it won't be of any help to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to provide the answer as a general guideline:
Both .ppt and .pptx files are glorified .zip files.
Use 7-zip or WinZip to open the .pptx and understand the structure.
Convert them into a .pptx file.
Each slide should now have a .xml file full of tags you can parse.
For example you will find tags for each text box with tags for that box's text nested inside.

Also: [python-pptx](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Mass convert by tweaking this VBA code: [Link for VBA](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00740_Batch_re-save_presentations-_update_older_presentations_to_newer_PowerPoint_version.htm)

Or using PowerShell: [Link for [PowerShell]](https://dlairman.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/convert-ppt-to-pptx-using-powershell/)

Comment: I understand your point, and thank you for the explanation about the .xml files. This method will not work though, the .xml files are just as disorganized as the real file. Let me be more clear, the black boxes surrounding the text and not one and the same, every element is separate, there is nothing linking them together in the file. The text is not inside the black box, they are simply overlaid to visually look like they are.

Comment: I made a test file similar to your image. The xml is well organized. Text in the text boxes is tagged with `<a:t>`, x & y positions are tagged with `<a:off>` (presumably offset). Both of these tags are within a `<p:sp>` tag. So you have text and location.

Comment: Ok, I like this. My schema is setup a little different but I see what you are looking at. That could work. The problem I see with this is I have thousands of these files. Doing some Googling I cannot find a library that converts `ppt` to `pptx`, doing this step manually will not be possible

Comment: Added two options for mass convert.